# url rewrite/formatting and php search form

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, search, url-rewriting

Happy new year!, i have a search form in php, and im using mod_rewrite, now, the thing that i want is this:

My normal url:
http://mywebsite.com/buscar.php?p=my+search+string&pag=1

TO:

mod rewrite:
http://mywebsite.com/buscar/my+search+string/1

How i can do that?

.htaccess

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^buscar/(^[a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]*$)/([0-9]+) buscar.php?p=$1&pag=$2`

HTML Form

```
<form action="buscar/1/" method="GET">
<div id="custom-search-input">
    <div class="input-group col-md-12">
        <input type="text" name="p" class="search-query form-control" placeholder="Buscar..." required autocomplete="off"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use javascript for that.

You can use this function:

```
function dosearch(frm) {
  var text = document.getElementsByClassName('search-query')[0].value;
  url = '/buscar/' + encodeURI(text) + '/1/';
  window.location = url;
  return false;
}
```

And inside your `<form>` element you need to add `onsubmit="return dosearch(this)"`.

Here is an example in jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dekelb/gkbgqzq4/

Comment: But, is there a way with .htaccess?

Comment: No, it's not related at all to `.htaccess`. It related to what happen in the browser (it happens before the request got to the server).

Comment: Ok, i'll try :)